# Restoring cursor position after typing :make

Tags: vim

I am using the following in my `.vimrc` to restore the cursor position after reopening the file:

```
" Copied from defaults.vim
" Put these in an autocmd group, so that you can revert them with:
" ":augroup vimStartup | au! | augroup END"
augroup vimStartup
  au!

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid, when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim) and for a commit message (it's
  " likely a different one than last time).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
    \ |   exe "normal! g`\""
    \ | endif

augroup END
```

The problem is that when I type `:make`, the cursor position is not restored; the cursor merely appears at the beginning of the line on which it was before typing `:make`.

Do you have any advise on how to fix this? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

The command `:make` doesn't seem to throw `BufReadPost`, so the autocommand will not execute.

You can do ``` :make | norm! `` ```

[`:help ''`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%27%27)